# Weird things with hyphenation

Tags: css, pseudo-class, css-hyphens

In Firefox, hyphenation works for both normal text and hyperlinks, for some reason that I don't understand.

Whereas I expect that since I have `:not(a)` pseudo-class, the selector should not affect `a` elements, that is, hyperlinks should not be hyphenated.

In other words, I expect that browser should understand `div :not(a)` as "any elements inside divs, except if such an element is `a` element". But it seems it doesn't work as I expect it...

---

Also, a side question.

Why does neither Chrome/Edge, nor Firefox hyphenation the word *incomprehensibility* if the first letter is uppercase?

---

My code:

```css
body {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 5em;
}

div :not(a) {
  hyphens: auto;
}

a {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p lang="en-US">
    incomprehensibility incomprehensibility incomprehensibility
    <a href="https://incomprehensibility.inc/">https://incomprehensibility.inc/</a>
    incomprehensibility
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: both selectors are not the same so not the same behavior.

Comment: "what is the difference between x and y?" - "the difference is that x is x, and y is y, so they are different." OK, thanks.

Comment: exactly, both selectors are *different*  targeting *different* elements so not sure what are you expecting. They have to behave *differently*

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry, there were serious problems with my question. I have completely re-write it.

Comment: hyphens is an inherited property so the link will inherit it from p

Comment: I still don't understand. I can even change the selector from `div :not(a)` to `:not(a)`, but Firefox still hyphenate hyperlinks for me. Arg-hhh!

Comment: your selector will select a parent element of `a` and then `a` will inherit the value from it. It doesn't matter if you select or not the `a`. Use `color` instead of hyphen to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply disable `hyphens` on `a`

```css
body {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 5em;
}

div {
  hyphens: auto;
}

a {
  hyphens: initial; /* this */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p lang="en-US">
    incomprehensibility incomprehensibility incomprehensibility
    <a href="https://incomprehensibility.inc/">https://incomprehensibility.inc/</a>
    incomprehensibility
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is something I have considered right from the beginning, but I was sure there must be a way to avoid property overriding, this is why I tried to use `:not()`.